# Generating libjingle VS solution and projects

Tags: scons, libjingle

I'm trying to generate the sln and vcproj files from the checkout of libjingle svn.
I set all the environment variables defined on README, but i keep getting the error:

```
C:\src>hammer --mode=all --vsproj

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "c:\src\libjingle\scons-local\scons-local-2.1.0\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 904, in _main
```

In fact there's no such file, but i can't find any info on how or where to create it.
Is this problem related to Python or SCons installation or is something missing on libjingle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems build system problem. You need to found SConstruct file (may be in Hammer build system SConstruct have different name) in libjingle project and use build command from directory where it placed.