# SCons- *** No SConstruct file found

Tags: python, scons

Installed SCons using 
 # cd scons-2.3.0
 # python setup.py install

After Installation, when i try to run scons , got the below error.

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.3.0/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 905, in _main

How to overcome this ???

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097442/generating-libjingle-vs-solution-and-projects

Comment: how to search the SConstruct file in scons

Comment: @user2439278 it's probably a bit late, but can you accept below answer (if it was helpful)? This will mark the question as resolved and help other users.

Answer (score 17):

There are 3 ways to specify the SConstruct file when using SCons, as follows:

- Execute `scons` from the root of the project, where there should be a SConstruct file. This is the most standard way.
- From a subdirectory of the project, where there should be a SConsctruct file at the root, execute `scons` with one of the following options (as seen by scons -h) to tell it to look up the directory structure for the SConstruct

> ```
> -u, --up, --search-up
> Search up directory tree for SConstruct, build targets at or 
> below current directory.
>
> -U
> Search up directory tree for SConstruct, build Default() targets 
> from local SConscript.
> ```

- Explicitly specify where the SConstruct file is, this is also available from `scons -h`

> ```
> -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE, --sconstruct=FILE
> Read FILE as the top-level SConstruct file.
> ```

Here is an example project in the directory `/home/notroot/projectDir` with the following directory structure:

```
SConstruct
subdir/file.hh
subdir/file.cc
```

Here is how to use the different options mentioned above:

**Option 1:**

Execute scons from the root project directory

```
# cd /home/notroot/projectDir
# scons
```

**Option 2:**

Execute scons from within the project directory and tell it to look up the dir hierarchy for the SConstruct

```
# cd /home/notroot/projectDir/subdir
# scons -u
```

**Option 3:**

Execute scons from within the project directory and specify the path of the SConstruct

```
# cd /home/notroot/projectDir/subdir
# scons -f /home/notroot/projectDir/SConstruct
```

Comment: could you please explain with example.. I had created and  stored SConstruct.py in  /usr/local/lib/scons-2.3.0/SCons/.

Comment: im new to this.please help me to fix this issue

Comment: @user2439278 Ok, I will update the answer with an example. But when I refer to a project, Im referring to the source code project, not the SCons installation project.