# Error trying to compile v8 on OSX Lion: scons: *** No SConstruct file found

Tags: homebrew, v8, scons, alljoyn

I'm getting the following error trying to compile v8 on OSX Lion:

```
sh-3.2# scons

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/usr/local/lib/scons-2.3.0/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 905, in _main
```

I've installed scons using Homebrew.

Comment: Either you havent defined a SConstruct or it cant be found. This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17185787/1158895

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCons- \*\*\* No SConstruct file found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182799/scons-no-sconstruct-file-found)

Answer (score 0):

Either cd to the directory that contains the SConstruct file, or use the -f flag to tell scons where it is. It works like "make", which needs to find a "Makefile" or it can't build anything.

Answer (score 0):

AllJoyn is built using xcodebuild for [OS X](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx/build-source). Using scons directly is not supported.