# Build error in Mongodb-C++driver

Tags: python, c++, mongodb

I am getting compile error while building a `mongodb C++` driver.

```
{
D:\TestPrograms\ThirdParty\C++\mongo-c-driver-1.1.0>scons --prefix=C:\MongoDb-Dr
iver --full --release --sharedclient --use-system-all --extrapath=D:\TestProgram
s\ThirdParty\C++\boost_1_52_0 --dynamic-windows install-mongoclient

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "D:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.2\SCons\Script\Main.py"
, line 920, in _main
}
```

Does anyone point the reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182799/scons-no-sconstruct-file-found - Does this help?

Comment: I have the same problem here ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on windows but on linux you can find a SConstruct file under the mongo-cxx-driver directory. You have to execute the scons command from there.