# My command prompt isn't recognizing "scons" as a command after I've downloaded it

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-prompt, scons

[A screenshot of the tutorial I'm currently trying to follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj0iY.jpg)

Basically my end goal here is to create C++ bindings for Godot using Scons. I've never used Scons or Python before.

I picked up the .zip file of the most recent scons release and the most recent python release. After that, I upgraded the pip installer and pip installed scons as you see the user in the screenshot has done. My problem begins with the third and final prompt she enters, where she simply enters "scons", and the command prompt returns "scons: **** No SConstruct file found". This seems to be a confirmation that scons is working properly, because the following steps in the tutorial don't work for me.

What I get instead is this: " 'scons' is not recognized as an internal or external command". Even if I shift-right click and open a command window literally from the scons file, it doesn't recognize "scons" as a command.

I'm at a complete loss here, and my more Python inclined friend has followed the same tutorial and arrived at the exact same issue, and she's actually experienced in Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SCons- \*\*\* No SConstruct file found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182799/scons-no-sconstruct-file-found)

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots, copy/paste the output. It's really really hard to read your  screenshot.

Comment: please paste the output from echo %PATH%

Comment: You say that you picked up the .zip file for *SCons*, but the tutorial (yes, I watched it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obeu2b2eN04 ) advises you to use `pip` to install *SCons* automatically. Which one did you use? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, in the screenshot you provided, it shows the name of the user from the tutorial. This isn't helpful, we have to see the messages and errors that you see on **your** machine in order to be able to help you out!