# Keep getting error while trying to add 3ds support to godot

Tags: cmd, scons, godot, 3ds

I am trying to develop for the 3ds on Godot. I have been following [this](https://www.gamebrew.org/wiki/Godot_3DS) tutorial. Everything has been going smoothly until I get this error while trying to run the command`scons p=3ds -j4 target=release`. I ran the python file given when downloading Scons and unzipped the file in a folder.
My error is this:

```
scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
```

Comment: My guess is that you are not running it in the correct path. You should have this Sconstruct file: https://github.com/Cruel/godot/blob/3ds/SConstruct - See also [SCons- *** No SConstruct file found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182799/scons-no-sconstruct-file-found)

Comment: I try git cloning and get this fatal: destination path 'godot' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: I believe you should have that file already, don't you? Double check. Anyway, git won't let you clone on a not empty folder (to clone, you would have to select another path or remove that one). Regardless, the idea is to execute scons where that file is. Edit: to reiterate, the current path where you are at when executing a command is important.

Comment: I tried doing c:\users\jeremy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\SCons\Script\Main.py scons p=3ds -j4 target=release but it just opened the file. I am quite new to this so I'm sorry if this sounds dumb. Also I just realised that I didn't give the full error in the beginning. the error was actually scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "c:\users\jeremy\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 944, in _main

Comment: This error has nothing to do with SCons itself. You need to run it where there is a SConstruct file present. Is there one in the directory you're in when you run scons?  Also how did you install SCons?

Comment: for downloading it I ran the python file given when downloading Scons and unzipped the file in a folder.